# border radius is not applying to image

Tags: html, css, font-family, google-font-api, border-radius

i am trying to comlete frontenmentor io challenges.I am as beginner in html and css i applied border radius as 10px to the image to round the edges of image. but it is not reflecting. also i added outfit as font family.but it is also not reflecting.i have given the html/css code here.Kindly help me to fix this

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@400;700&display=swap');

*body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: hsl(212, 45%, 89%);
}

.main{
    width: 300px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.main .img{
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 1rem;
    
}

.container{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
}

.main h1{

    font-family: "outfit" sans-serif;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | QR code component</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container"><div class="main">
    <img class= "img" src="/images/image-qr-code.png">
    <h1>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</h1>
    <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level </p>
  </div>
</div>



 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're not adding the border radius to img you're adding it to the main class if you want your image to have border radius of 10px  just add that particular rule in `.main .img` selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border-radius needs to be applied to the .img. However, you won't see it given there is also a padding of a greater amount (1rem). This snippet removed that so you get to see the border-radius.

To increase the generality, as you have given a fixed width and height to the img, I have included an object-fit: contain to ensure all the image is always seen whatever its aspect ratio (you could alternatively use cover to ensure that full size is covered, though it could mean there is some cropping of the image).

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@400;700&display=swap');
*,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: hsl(212, 45%, 89%);
}

.main {
  width: 300px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.main .img {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main h1 {
  font-family: "outfit" sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->


  <title>Frontend Mentor | QR code component</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <img class="img" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/300/300">
      <h1>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</h1>
      <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level </p>
    </div>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Note, there was also a *body at the start of the CSS. I have just guessed that you meant to remove default margin etc from all elements.

Answer (score 0):

add `overflow: hidden` css in `.main` class.

The problem is you have added radius to the parent of the image. When content overflow out of radius, they are visible by default.

So to hide the content you need to put overflow hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have added `border` and set `border-radius: inherit` (this will simply set the border of child as per parent element's property) to `img` class.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Outfit:wght@400;700&display=swap');
*body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: hsl(212, 45%, 89%);
}

.main {
  max-width: 250px;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-justify: none;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.main .img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: inherit;
}

.main p {
  text-justify: inter-word;
  text-align: justify;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.main h1 {
  font-family: "outfit" sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->


  <title>Frontend Mentor | QR code component</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <img class="img" src="/images/image-qr-code.png" />
      <h1>Improve your front-end skills by building projects</h1>
      <p>Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skills to the next level </p>
    </div>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the border to the image not the parent div your code should be something like this

`.main img{ border-radius: 10px; }`